# How can I keep track of position from multiple text files?

Tags: c, file, position, fseek

I have written so far the code below. I want to open all my fptg_%d.txt files as my varialble Time increases and at the next timeslot (Time=Time+12) I want to get the next line from the line I had at the previous timeslot.

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

    int src,dest;
    int rollnumber;
    double gentime;

    int i=1;

    static unsigned long pos = 0;

    FILE *file;
    char filename_format[] = "fptg_%d.txt";
    char filename[sizeof(filename_format) + 4];

    double Time=12.0; 
    int insertedpackets[1000]; 

    struct node * head = NULL;




    for (Time=12.0; Time<60.0; Time=Time+12.0){
        
     for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
        
        char to_open[32];
        snprintf(to_open,32, "fptg_%d.txt", i);
        printf("\n\nFPTG_%d.txt\n", i);
        
        if ((file = fopen(to_open, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }else{
                
                fseek(file , pos, SEEK_CUR);
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
                sscanf(line,"%d %d %d %lf",&rollnumber, &src, &dest,&gentime);
                printf("%s", line);
                printf("%d\n",sscanf(line, " %d %d %d %lf", &rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime));
                printf("gentime=%.1f\n", gentime);
                pos = ftell(file);
               
            if (gentime<Time){
               
                printf("ok\n");

                printf("Time=%0.1f\n", Time);
             
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

The output I am getting:

```
   FPTG_1.txt
   1       1       3       1.6
   4
   gentime=1.6
   ok
   Time=12.0


   FPTG_2.txt
   2       2       19      14.0
   4
   gentime=14.0


   FPTG_1.txt
   3       1       20      25.9
   4
   gentime=25.9


   FPTG_2.txt
   4       2       5       39.5
   4
   gentime=39.5


   FPTG_1.txt

   -1
   gentime=39.5


   FPTG_2.txt
           2       6       52.6
    4
   gentime=0.6
   ok
   Time=36.0


   FPTG_1.txt

   -1
   gentime=0.6
   ok
   Time=48.0


   FPTG_2.txt
           2       17      64.8
   4
   gentime=0.8
   ok
   Time=48.0
```

As you can see it has some errors, but also  it keeps the position from the previous file and goes to the next to one. (From line 1 of the first file, it goes to line 2 from the next file). What I want to do, is from line 1 of the first file to go also to line 1 of the second file, but then return to line 2 of the first file and then to line 2 of the second file. How can I have that?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you open each file again and again? (BTW: You don't close any of them.) You could just open all of them before your loop and then just use the opened file and continue reading the current position.

Comment: When dealing with text files, `fseek` isn't really that useful. You can get back to a position you got via `ftell` inside the same file but using that position to set position in another file isn't something I would bet on.

Comment: Turn `pos` into an array (one position per file).

Comment: "All my files" – you are opening *two* files becuase `i` used to make the filename has two values. Consider unrolling the inner `i` loop and opening the two files at the start. Then you won't need any `pos` or `ftell` or `fseek`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did not understand what exactly you think I should do. But thank you again for your help, I have made progress since yesterday!!

Comment: @IanAbbott So helpful, thnak you a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I see you used yesterday's feedback to improve the code. But do please take on board the idea of posting a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (*complete* code).

Comment: What I suggest is to write a function that processes one line which is passed to it. First open `fptg_1.txt` and `fptg_2.txt`. Then inside the time loop, you read one file and pass the string read to the function. Then you read the other file and do the same. No seeking, simple.

Comment: I have not post before any Minimal Reproducible Example, so I do not know how to do that. Do I have to make a new question, or edit this one?

Comment: @WeatherVane Also for the function you suggested, could you please gine me an example of what you thought?

Comment: You have all the code, but I didn't mention how you would handle `Time`. In yesterday's code, you attempted (and failed) to return that from the function. Make the function type `double`.

Comment: Time is okay so far, I mean it does what I want. Do you mean my variable gentime?